# Bind TreeView with Sitemap

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a Sitemap and I am planning to query it programmatically and filter it, something like

```
from SiteMapNode smnode in SiteMap.RootNode.GetAllNodes()
..do something
```

My question is how do I approach the above. I mean on what event can I query it and how to then bind it to the TreeView?

Answer (score 1):

You should use SiteMapDataSource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227441.aspx

and bind to that datasrouce